# How to keep separate css links in Astro at build time

Tags: javascript, html, css, astrojs

In Astro.js, when i put these lines in a .astro file :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href={ Astro.resolve('../styles/preloader.scss') }>
<link rel="stylesheet" href={ Astro.resolve('../styles/application.scss') } media="print" onload="this.onload=null;this.media='all'">
```

the result I get at build time is this :

(I am building a multi language site. The 'en' in en.ffae6e3d.css is from the english page /en )

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/application.ddd2d855.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/en.ffae6e3d.css">
```

How can I get this result ?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/preloader.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/application.css" media="print" onload="this.onload=null;this.media='all'">
```

This is the (expected) result I get indevelop mode.

Comment: `Astro.resolve` has been deprecated https://docs.astro.build/en/migrate/#deprecated-astroresolve.

Comment: I don't think you can manipulate how things load with Astro.

Comment: What's your goal?

Answer (score 0):

You could try `is:inline` for loading resource files on the client side without compiling it during build.

https://docs.astro.build/en/reference/directives-reference/#isinline